# How to wrap then unwrap div when resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried `if else` statements and it should be fairly simple but I cant seem to reverse the wrap after resizing above 650px.

Basically, I'm trying to get the boxes wrapped in a div when window is below 650 width and then unwrapped after resizing above 650px.

How can I do that?

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 650)
    $('.box').wrap("<div class='boxwrap'><div/>")

});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 650)
    $('.box').unwrap("<div class='boxwrap'><div/>")

});
```

```css
  #cat-area {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#cat-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 92.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #cat-area {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
  }
  #cat-container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 92.5%;
    display: block;
  }
  .box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px 0px;
  }
  .boxwrap {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cat-area">
  <div id="cat-container">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL.  It's not necessary.

Comment: $('.box').unwrap() should be enough, no need to specify the div

Comment: Is there a problem?  If so, please state it.

Comment: @cale_b the problem is with my jquery, not not sure how to get the div to unwrap when above 650px window size

Comment: Have you considered / tried the comments above?

Comment: @cale_b yup and no luck

Comment: What's not just use a simple CSS media query? https://jsfiddle.net/thordopr/

Comment: because you cant add a line of html or wrap an elemnt in a div using css

Comment: Problem is that resize event fires with each resize. Resize/drag your browser a little and you have 10-20 resize events. So, you keep wrapping when resizing below 650px, and end up with a shipload of `.boxwrap` divs wrapped around `.box`. which doesn't look like will easily unwrap. You need to test before wrapping.. or use a flag.

Comment: @TechGirl unwrap SHOULD use a selector otherwise it will remove whatever parent element it finds with each resize event!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem to this myself. Here is a simple demonstration of how you can do this:

1. Note the page width initially
2. On resize, after a brief timeout (after resizing has stopped), note the new width
3. Compare the two values to determine whether we should take action or not
4. Reset our width for comparison to the new width, for the next time we resize

Run the following snippet, expand it to full screen, and adjust the browser size to see it working.

```js
$(function() {
  var resizeTimer;
  var initialSize = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      var delayedSize = $(window).width();
      // if we resize the page but we don't cross the 650 threshold, do nothing
      if ((initialSize > 650 && delayedSize > 650) || (initialSize < 650 && delayedSize < 650)) {
        return
      }
      // else if we resize the page and cross the 650 threshold, do something
      else {
        if (delayedSize > 650) {
          $('#cat-container').unwrap('#cat-area');
        } else if (delayedSize <= 650) {
          $('#cat-container').wrap('<div id="cat-area"></div>');
        }
      }

      initialSize = delayedSize;
    }, 250);
  });
});
```

```css
#cat-area {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 10px;
}
#cat-container {
  background-color: slategray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat-area">
  <div id="cat-container">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <img class="box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```